# Azure AppService plan CPU utilization High

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-app-service-plans

We are facing an issues on azure appservice plan. We are using standard s1 plan. But suddenly it's pick became high after 8 hours regularly. hence, application CPU utilization is normal. application runs properly. no issues found over there.

But when we take it on shared plan,its running fine and well. Please suggest us what we can do?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service to troubleshoot it.

Azure provides built-in diagnostics to assist with debugging an App Service app. You need to enable it following the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs).

Comment: I found something that appService Plan CPU is fully difference from appservice application cpu utilization.. Is it right?